# Shuffling a list with maximum distance travelled

Tags: python, algorithm, list, permutation, shuffle

Say I have a list `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]` that I want to shuffle.

I'd like to find algorithm that would randomly permute that data with the restriction that no element would be more than N spaces away from its starting position. So with `N = 2`, `a` would never appear below the third position of the starting list. With `N = 0`, the algorithm would return the list without any changes, and `N = len(list) - 1`, it would function exactly like a normal shuffling algorithm

For example, using python syntax:

```
>>> restrictedShuffle([a, b, c, d, e, f, g], N=2)
[a, c, b, f, d, g, e] 
>>> restrictedShuffle([a, b, c, d, e, f, g], N=1)
[b, a, c, e, d, f, g]
>>> restrictedShuffle([a, b, c, d, e, f, g], N=0)
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Does such an algorithm exist?